# Is Pearson's R inappropriate for measuring regression accuracy?

Tags: regression, pearson-r

People seem to chirp if you use Pearson's R correlation coefficent between predicted and actual values in order to interpret how well your regressor actually works.

I have never got a clear answer why this is so. People often say "Your regression model is non-linear, hence, the Pearson will not work".

???

If my regressor is good, I would expect predicted vs actual to be linearly correlated, so why is it a bad idea to use Pearson's R, if the underlying model is non-linear?

Comment: It seems like you have a lot of terminology confused, such as using "power" to mean "predictive accuracy" (I think) and "regressor" to mean "dependent variable" (or do you mean "model"?). Pleae edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Sorry. By power, I indeed meant predictive accuracy

Comment: the statement, if my regressor is good the predicted vs. actual are linearly correlated, seems flawed too. it is not clear what you mean by a good regressor. perhaps you mean if you use the correct model, i.e. have no variables omitted from the equation and use the correct functonal form (link). however, then the statement still wouldnt be correct, since the correct model may be non-linear.

Comment: I am measuring `corr(pred_y, actual_y)`. If that is 0.99, then it would make sense that I have a good regressor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simpler reason not to use Pearson's $r$ to compare a model's predicted values to actual values, which is that $r$ corrects for a linear transformation between the compared variables.

For example, suppose that a model predicts the top speeds of four racing snails to be 10, 17, 25, and 100 m/s respectively, but their actual top speeds are .003, .0058, .009, and .039 m/s. Obviously, the predictions are nowhere near accurate, but the correlation between observed and predicted values is 1.

Comment: nice explanation. What should I measure then? Would reporting spearman's or tau be better?

Comment: It depends on the scale of the dependent variable, but root mean squared error and mean absolute error are often good choices for continuous variables.

Comment: @sponge_knight no reasonable measure of correlation makes sense as a measure of predictive accuracy

Comment: Okay - it makes sense not to use $R$. Why do people use $R^2$ then?

Comment: @sponge Within the context of linear regression, it can make sense to use $R$ or $R^2$ to measure other things that predictive accuracy (though broadly speaking its value is somewhat limited).  If you're asking me why do some people nonetheless use $R$ or $R^2$ to measure predictive accuracy in general settings (and you'd be right to think that they do - we get questions about it all the time) -- in spite of its unsuitability -- what can I say? People do a lot of things that make no sense to me. Part of the problem is simply not understanding the tools, part of it comes from other things.

Comment: @sponge_knight It's important to think about what you need a model to do well, and measure *that*.

Comment: Yeah - sorry, it is weird to get conflicting forces about this topic; i see a lot of papers, even from reputed institutions use correlation to measure regressor accuracy. But the scikit-learn say clearly in their documentation that $R^2$ can be used for quantifying how well a regressor performs: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score

Comment: `People do a lot of things that make no sense to me. `

So, you're saying that ALL correlation measures including Kendall, Spearman, and Pearson are bad for inferring accuracy? Do you have sources for this? Because you are the first person that has said this. Note that I'm referring to the context of non-linear regression.

Comment: @sponge_knight My snails example also has Spearman and Kendall correlations of 1.

Comment: It seems that in this example, Pearson's $R$ is still telling you something useful, namely that there's an affine transformation (in this case, 
$ x \rightarrow .0004 x - .001$) which takes your predictions to the correct values.

Comment: @sponge_knight Note that the $R^2$ referenced in that scikit-learn doc is the general coefficient of determination ($1 - $ Fraction of Unexplained Variance) not necessarily the square of the correlation coefficient.  Note the comment "R^2 score may be negative".  In particular it would be the square of Pearson's $r$ for linear least squares, but not necessarily in other cases.

Comment: Thanks for that comment Tim. Considering that there is an affine transformation, then I'd still argue it is a good measure for accuracy. I still don't know why some reputed researchers are using this (I'm sure you could find dozens with a quick Google search).

Comment: @sponge_knight It is an open secret that fields of science that use statistics tend to have many statistically poor traditions.