# What is the most meaningful method to test whether two versions of the same measuring tool are producing consistent results?

Tags: variance, agreement-statistics, coefficient-of-variation

I have got myself confused as to what method will best tell me whether the results from two measuring devices are producing the same results.

Basically the subject will wear two devices while performing an activity and we are testing whether the results between the two devices are the same or not.

I am not too familiar with the coefficient of variation (CV) often used in sports science research, but could this potentially be used to test whether the CV's produced from each device are similar or not?

Comment: Whether they measure the same on average, & which is most meaningful are different questions. How many measures will you have from each subject from each device?

Comment: Each device is measuring the force and velocity the subject exerts while performing the specified motion. Each subject will have 36 measures of force and 36 measures of velocity from each device, so 144 measures in total. I am looking to see whether the devices are capturing the same amount of force and velocity.

Answer (score 1):

In psychometrics, the degree of agreement between two instruments that are supposed to measure the same thing is called convergent validity. Convergent validity is usually measured with correlation, but this is a mistake because [correlation corrects for a linear transformation, which you don't want here, because you want to assess equality rather than mere association](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/224223/14076). Better ideas include root mean square error, mean absolute error, and (in the case of a categorical scale) simply the proportion agreement.